# automatically remote deploy from gogs inside docker

Tags: git, docker, githooks, gogs

We have a gogs server installed with docker in machine `gitbase`. Also, we have a `frontend` server as web server.

What I want to do is to write code in my local machine, push to `gitbase`. And then automatically deploy the code to `frontend` server using `git hooks`.

In the `git hooks`, I wrote `post-receive` hook which `ssh` into the `frontend` server to `git clone` the repo. But it shows `Host key verification failed` error.

I have passwordless login to `frontend` from `gitbase` using username `root`. So my guess is that `gogs` inside `docker` try to ssh using a different username, how can I find what username it used? Or is there other way to do the remote deployment?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the details of the post-receive hook script to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which user one has created while setting up the Gogs server.
I doubt user would be anything but root. Eg., git or gogs.

Easy way to find this out is to observe the ssh clone url. It generally have format like *user@server:path*.

Try configure ssh script using this *user*.

BTW: I would recommend using *post-update* ssh hook instead of post-receive.